# Detect class change on <body> with MutationObserver?

Tags: jquery, mutation-observers

I have a `<body>` called `<body id="check-in-body">` and I want to detect when the class changes on this. It can change from `class="theme-1"` to `class="theme-2"` and so on.

I have the code below, but I cannot make it work. I was able to get it to work partly when removing `&& (mutation.attributeName === "class")` and `attributeFilter: ['class']` from the code below. But this triggers all the time because when I have a modal visible `style="overflow: hidden;"` will be added to `body` and I think this is what triggers it.
How do I only listen to class change on `body`?

```
function searchBackgroundFetch() {
  var element = document.querySelector('#check-in-body');
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if ((mutation.type === "attributes") && (mutation.attributeName === "class")) {
        console.log('Yeah');
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(element, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['class']
  });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to something like this? Why can't you just have a global function like `setTheme` and everything that needs to set a theme calls it to set a theme. Then you can put your needed behaviour there?

Comment: Your code works4me. BTW both conditions are always true hence unneeded. I guess the page may swap the entire `body` node e.g. via document.documentElement.replaceChild or similar approach in which case you'll have to observe `childList:true` mutations on document.documentElement too.